# ASP.NET Attribute Routes and default routes can work together?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I've a project written in NET Core 2.1, in which I've a bunch of Controller/Actions with Attribute routes on them.
Something like:

```
[Route("~/test")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult ById(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And on the Startup I've just the default:

```
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
{
    routeBuilder.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

So, the application is resolving `/test/42` as expected, but there's no way to have `/products/byid?id=42` working... If I just comment out the attributes from the controller the default route take place.

Is there a way to have them work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: Change it to `[Route("/products")]` and try again.

In detail:

If you have the RouteAttribute applied to a controller or action method, then that controller/action method will only respond to that specified route. In that specific example you gave there it will only execute if you browse to `/~test/65`.

If you want controller/action methods to work with the names by default, then try using the `[controller]` and `[action]` flag like so:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("[action]/{id:int}")] // /Products/ById/5
    public IActionResult ById(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Your default route in ASP.NET Core is a route that MVC will fall back to if no controllers hit the route you specified. In that case, `/Products/ById/5` would have also worked.

By default, it maps to the `Home` controller and the `Index` action method, which is your default home page. If the route is just `/` then that action will be executed.

You can also do this to just specify the route you want directly

```
[Route("/api/products")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("by-id/{id:int}")] // /api/products/by-id/5
    public IActionResult ById(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also try the suggestion that Joe tried, as it's also a method. But in the end you can fine tune your routes and can have multiple routes on one controller or action if you'd like. Try and experiment yourself, but have a look at the documentation for more information.

Most likely, you don't want to modify the default route, and adjust your RouteAttribute to your liking. Read about [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and [routing to controller actions using app.UseMvc()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in the links that I have provided.

Comment: I didn't thought about the flags, but actually adding both [Route("[controller]")] AND [Route("~/test", Order = 1)] on the controller and [Route("[action]")] AND [HttpGet("{id:int}", Order = 1)] on the action I'm getting the result. Is a bit redundant but in the end I've to do this just for the actions under custom routes. Many thanks!

Comment: You can look at Joe's answer for removing redundancy. The docs also provide a nice way to completely eliminate redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use both attribute routes and conventional routes in the same application. However as soon as you mark a controller or action with an attribute route, then you cannot route to that controller or action at all using conventional routes. You can still use conventional routes for other controllers.

If you want the attribute route to use /products then you can change it:

```
[Route("~/products")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult ById(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

but you cannot use both types of routes for the same controller/action

The only workaround I know of is you can create another controller that inherits from the controller with the attribute routes (make the action methods virtual). Then you can leave off the attribute routes with the new sub classed controller and you can route to it with conventional routes and just invoke the base class action methods.

Example:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
        public virtual IActionResult ById(int id)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}

namespace MyOtherNamespace
{

    public class ProductsController : MyNamespace.ProductsController
    {

        public override IActionResult ById(int id)
        {
            base.ById(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can route to the ProductsController using conventional routes while the base controller uses attribute routes.

Comment: I added example of inherited controller

Comment: edited to show you can use the same controller class name with different namespaces

Comment: Also a valid solution, but the need to extend the controller overriding the actions is a bit too much to maintain

Comment: ok but the other answer doesn't show how to use both attribute routes and conventional routes at the same time which I thought was part of your question.

Comment: But it gives me the clue to use the [Route("[controller]")] in conjunction with my attribute. As you both said, in the end, they're not supposed to work together and you've to do some kind of workaround